# Hull Derivatives Probability Density

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, finance, quantitative-finance

I am using option data to calculate the implied probability density; essentially copying the Appendix: Determining Implied Risk-Neutral Distributions from Volatility Smiles from Hull's book.

[image]

My question is his about his example:

[image]

Using the code `math.exp(0.03*0.25)*(((4.045+3.055)-(2*3.549))/(0.5^2))` gives the answer `0.00806` not `0.0057`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No. Hull's wrong. Using a calculator, you'll find 0.00806 too.

Comment: thank you, was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hull is not wrong. The difference is due to rounding.

The option values below, calculated with Black-Scholes, will give Hull's result of 0.005695928, rounded to 0.0057

**BS VALUES**

$4.0449121994898

$3.0546354450165

$3.549067151214

Comment: You are right `math.exp(0.03*0.25)*(((4.0449121994898+3.0546354450165)-(2*3.549067151214))/(0.5**2))` gives the correct output. I have deleted my answer and accepted yours.